# Retriving mac-id from http request

Tags: javascript, php, ip, host, mac-address

I am working on an application which requires me to make use of mac-id for authentication purposes, meaning a user should be able to login from only one particular machine always.

In the case he/she tries logging in through some other machine, despite of giving correct login credentials, he/she should not be authenticated because mac-id of that machine different.

How can I achieve this functionality? I have mac-id stored against every user in the user table. My question is how can I retrieve mac-id from the login request? Is this possible through JS (like JS will capture it and put it in a hidden field) or php?

Could any one help me out with the code please.

Comment: Bad news apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5074163/998096

Comment: More bad news: iOS 8 randomizes the MAC address for privacy reasons.  And users of other operating systems can change their MAC address.  So using a MAC address for authentication is a bad idea.