# Get device MAC address

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, mac-address

I want to build a website and an app to go with it. I'll use MAC addresses for security and authentication. For the app, I'll use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and for the website, of course, PHP and jQuery.

1. How can I get the MAC address of the device/computer using
   [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)?
2. How can I get the MAC address of the device/computer using PHP or jQuery?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because of the security concerns involved. At the least it'll probably involve a convoluted solution with ActiveX or a Java Applet, which is untenable on mobile. See [MAC addresses in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript) and [How to get MAC address of client using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074139/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-using-php)