# Who's There? - Tracking Site Visits

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, logging, sinatra

I am writing a website with sinatra and heroku, and I want to find a way to track every visit to my site. I have seen actual analytics programs (e.g. [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)) and have chosen not to use them because I would like to learn how to do this myself.

My definition of a visit:

> A visit happens when someone or something (robot) visits your site. It consists of one or more page views/ hits. One visitor can make multiple visits to your site.

Source: http://www.opentracker.net/article/hits-or-pageviews

For each visit, I would like to track:

1. Visitor IP address

   Time visit began (page was opened)

   Time visit ended (page was closed)

This website is not viewed very often and so I would like to log each visit in a postgres database accessed with activerecord.
The way that logging would work would be this:

1. User accesses page
2. Session is started, `ip`, `mac_address`, `time`, and `view_id` are logged in `Visit`
3. Each page viewed is logged in `PageView`
4. User closes page
5. Session is cleared, `time` and `view_id` are logged in `Visit`

**DATABASE FORMAT**

- Visits (Table)

  - ip (Column, string)
  - mac_address (Column, string)
  - view_id (Column, int)
  - time (Column, datetime)
- PageViews (Table)

  - page (Column, string)
  - time (Column, datetime)
  - view_id (Column, int)

Sample Migration File:

```
class Main < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :visits do |item|
        item.string :ip
        item.string :mac_address
        item.datetime :time
        item.int :visit_id
    end
    create_table :pageviews do |item|
        item.int :visit_id
        item.string :page
        item.datetime :time
  end
end
```

Comment: i think you won't be able to get any client mac-add without his permission.

Comment: To extend on the above: the MAC address is a l[ayer-2 construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_2:_Data_Link_Layer) (only) and you don't see it over the routed Internet.

Comment: So can I request it from the client? Or should I remove that from the question?

Comment: You can get the client's MAC address in javascript, if they are running Windows and allow you to install an ActiveX control check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074139/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-using-php

Comment: @authprivate Thank you, I have added that to the question.

Comment: Why do you even need the MAC address? If it's to discern different visitors using the same IP then use a cookie.

Comment: Just to keep, for records. No real reason why.

Comment: And what was your question?

Comment: How to track site visits... Oh I see. Good point. I will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each visit, I would like to track:
>
> 1. Visitor IP address
> 2. Time visit began (page was opened)
> 3. Time visit ended (page was closed)

You also had MAC addresses in the list before, but just to reiterate - they aren't used to route the internet, just local networks, so it's close to pointless to save that information, even if you could get at it.

HTTP is a stateless protocol, which means #3 is not possible via HTTP methods, but it can be done via javascript. Probably the easiest way is to poll at an acceptable interval, updating the time.

#1 and #2 are already caught by your basic server logs, they'd be what I'd use - why duplicate effort? - but I'll add how to use Sinatra to do it via the model.

If you use a `before` filter you can catch #1 and #2 easily. The [Request object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object) has some of what you want, and you'll need the time, and to make sure it's a unique user for that ip:

```
before do
  # this is pseudo code, Sequel style, you can work this bit out
  # for ActiveRecord
  user =
    if user_id = session[:user]
      User[user_id]
    else
      User.create
    end

  # you may want to check if there's an existing session for this page
  # as refreshes would run this again. It's up to you.
  user.add_visit Visit.create(page: request.path,ip: request.ip, start: Time.now.rfc2822])
  session[:analytics] = visit.id
  session[:user] = user.session_id # *don't* just bung the
                                   # user id in there
end
```

You'll need a route to log the end time to

```
patch "/analytics", :provides => :json do
  visit_id = session[:analytics]
  user = User[ :session_id => session[:user] ]
  visit = user.visits.find(:id => visit_id)
  visit.end = Rack::Utils.rfc2822(params[:end])
  visit.save
  halt 204 # take your pick of success numbers
           # you should also check for errors
           # and check the input is valid
           # and you may want to return some JSON to the
           # calling javascript.
  # Also think about how to restrict access to this
  # route to only authorised callers. Since you're providing the
  # javascript, you can place variables in them by generating
  # parts on the fly and serving it via a Sinatra route etc.
end
```

I'm not going to write the javascript, that should be straightforward.

Note, I basically pulled this code out of my backside so consider any or all of it likely to break and be shaky, but it's so you *get the idea*. Like I mentioned above, I'd probably cut most of this and use the logs and some judicious regex.