# Is there any way to get MAC address through web browser (except ie)

Tags: php, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, mac-address

I want to recognize identical client users with their MAC address and it's possible only in Internet Explorer.
I also want mac address of who is using chrome, firefox etc.

It's okay to make users to download files and that file should give mac address of that pc to the browser.

Is it possible??

Comment: A strong No, You cannot get MAC address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MAC address of client using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074139/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-using-php)

Comment: What does this question have to do with the web browser control?