# How to get a website connected device IMEI or MAC Address using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, imei

I want to build a system where once user login, i get his connected device IMEI to store with login credentials.
So how to get that connected device IMEI to restrict user for that 1 device in future logins.

I am Using Core PHP

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you share some code?

Comment: You can't get a remote device's IMEI using PHP alone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074139/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-using-php

Comment: i have tried some codes but that did't work for me. so i deleted it. now posted here to take some best answers and solution

Comment: in that link, mentioned that if the client side is using windows then can get MAC but what about other platforms like Macintosh ? Jagdish

Comment: The answer is from 2011. Should't work in Edge.

Comment: But... Why do you even want to know the MAC or IMEI?

Comment: You cant, unless you capture that on the device and send it to the PHP. Note: capturing that requires a Permission as that info is considered not to be generally available to apps

Comment: I need it because this is client's requirements, clients need to restrict one user only to one device. This is like udemy website. But that is clients' strange requirements.

Comment: How can i achieve this to restrict a user to access / login from 1 device ? Any alternative solutions to IMEI or MAC ? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** get the IMEI of a device using php, is just not possible. You can get the MAC of your clients only if they are connected in the **same network** as your server. If they are on the internet, you are not going to get their MAC, the MAC will be for the default gateway.

If you want to restrict only one user, you can do like anybody else and use sessions for a valid user id like email and check if a session for that email is active and then either deny login or login the new device and delete the session for the previous one.

Comment: But i want to restrict the user to login with only 1 device, the device on which the user has registered. is this possible ? how to do this ?