# How can I get the clients MAC address in PHP for https requests?

Tags: php

I was trying the below code but it is not working working in the cloud server but is working in my localhost.

```
ob_start();
system('ipconfig /all');
$mycom=ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
$findme = "Physical";
$pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme);
$mac=substr($mycom,($pmac+36),17);
echo $mac;
```

Comment: After removing the ob* also no result

Comment: What's in `$mycom`?, presuming your *cloud server* is running windows and has ipconfig installed.

Comment: *"How can I get the clients MAC address in PHP...?*" - short answer, you can't (in general).

Comment: Cloud server in running on Linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get MAC address of client using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074139/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-using-php)

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) - PHP runs on the server so running a `system('ip a)` command will merely give you information about the server, **not** the client.

Comment: Okay. So, how can get the MAC address of a client machine?

Comment: (How to get MAC address of client using PHP?) is not helpfull for me