# PHP: Get client MAC address

Tags: php, mac-address

i want to get the client MAC address from an connected socket. usually you can get the IP-address via

```php
$ip = \stream_socket_get_name($socket, true);
```

is there any chance to get the MAC at the same way? i know all about the facts that the real MAC is only available in a local network and also this hack:

```php
exec("arp $ip");
```

but i want to avoid to execute an external tool.

volker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get MAC address of client using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074139/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-using-php)

Comment: But if it is your app protocol, you can build it in yourself. Put the client MAC into your communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way, the MAC is not included in the TCP/IP stack and once routed, the client MAC is not visible.
MAC = Layer 2

-- edit:

But if it is your app protocol, you can build it in yourself. Put the client MAC into your communication.

Comment: at the end, it is just an HTTP request.

Comment: Then it is not possible, unless you provide the browser